# How do I split 2-2-2 words with the python split() method

Tags: python, split

I want to split the texts into 2-2-2 words as I mentioned in the title. but i cant do that

```py
song= ["Rolling in the deep wish you"]
iwantformat_output=["Rolling in", "the deep", "wish you"]

song= ["Rolling in the deep wish you"]
a=song.split(" ")
```

The crazy thing I tried was to replace 1 space with 2 space characters in split(" ") i have no more idea

Comment: You could do a regular split, then join the first two words back together, and the third and fourth words, etc.

Comment: how i can write, im beginner in

Comment: You already know how to split into individual words. See the linked duplicate for grouping *that* result into pairs of words, which you can then put together by any usual technique.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have an array of a single string.

Here's my solution, using numpy's reshape:

```py
import numpy as np
song = "Rolling in the deep wish you"
pairs = [" ".join(k) for k in np.reshape(song.split(" "), (-1, 2))]
print(pairs)
```

I don't know any method that doesn't involve splitting every word and then stitching them back together.

if you don't want to use `numpy`, you could try this:

```py
song = "Rolling in the deep wish you"
song_words = song.split(" ")
pairs = [" ".join(song_words[i:i+2]) 
         for i in range(0, len(song_words)-1, 2)]
print(pairs)
['Rolling in', 'the deep', 'wish you']
```

but you have to be careful about edge cases, i.e. what do you get if your input has an even or odd number of words.

Answer (score 0):

```
song = "Rolling in the deep wish you" 
song_split = song.split(' ')
iwantformat_output = [" ".join(song_split[i:i+2]) for i in range(0, len(song_split), 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re
re.findall('[^ ]+ [^ ]+', song)
```